# WMS-C Google Maps v2 Android

Tags: google-maps, wms, android

I'm have added a map from a WMS-server in Google Maps v2 for Android using the code provided from this site: http://www.azavea.com/blogs/labs/2013/01/wms-on-android/ . The tiles are downloaded and displayed but something is not working properly. The map looks blurry and the detail level is low.

I have tried fiddling around with the bbox parameters and if I increase the value for each point multiplying by 4, I can see a greater resolution and more details in the map but the tiles are way off.

Do I have to add some parameters to the wmsurl like resolution or something?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your projection is correct and the tile request is 256px by 256px

```
private static final String GEOSERVER_FORMAT =
            "http://yourApp.org/geoserver/wms" +
            "?service=WMS" +
            "&version=1.1.1" +              
            "&request=GetMap" +
            "&layers=yourLayer" +
            "&bbox=%f,%f,%f,%f" +
            "&width=256" +
            "&height=256" +
            "&srs=EPSG:900913" +
            "&format=image/png" +               
            "&transparent=true";
```

source:
http://www.azavea.com/blogs/labs/2013/01/wms-on-android/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The tile request is 256 and projection is 900913. I have tried using osmdroid too, where the map displayed properly. It's a huge difference comparing the level of details / resolution between osmdroid and Google Maps. I'm getting the map from the Norwegian Mapping Authority, I don't know if I have misunderstood anything: http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=no&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=no&ie=UTF-8&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.kartverket.no%2FKart%2FKartverksted%2FVisningstjenester%2FCache-tjenester%2F&act=url